# Delphi FireMonkey - How to set a file to deploy to different locations on Android and iOS?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am an old-timer to Delphi but only very new to Delphi XE5 and FireMonkey.

I am trying to write a cross-platform iOS/Android app to display some videos.

From tutorials like this -> http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2013/11/23/43005/ <- I can deploy a file, and I can play it under both platforms.

HOWEVER, this deployment screen is driving me nuts; no matter whether I select 'Android platform' or 'iOS platform' whenever I add a file it shows as being for "[Android,iOSDevice,iOSSimulator]" platforms. I can't work out how to just add a file to one platform, or how to remove platforms.

I can see the .dproj file is plain text but surely I don't need to resort to editing it? Why can't I simply say, from Project/Deployment, this file is for Android and this file is for iOS?

Thanks !

Comment: As a work around you can use some IFDEF's in the dpr file or in your units.

Comment: I am unsure about using an IFDEF in the dpr but it's not a code issue (ie IFDEF in units isn't relevant) because the problem is with deploying to the right folder on the target device, not with using TPath in code to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the file or files, select them and double click on the platforms column. You should go into edit mode with a button to the right (three dots on it). Now if that fails the first time try double clicking some more. The designer is very badly made for file deployment.

Ok then click the button with the three dots and you will get a dropdown with all available platforms. Select the ones you want and that is it.

I should write a resource management app as the designer that comes with Delphi is horrible, but I have no time to work on it :(

Comment: Thanks Runner! That helped immensely. You're very right; the interface is not at all intuitive but now I know the trick :) Much appreciated.